# PositionError Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 404

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Geolocation HTML5 API. I am using angular.js. I write a small factory function

```
myApp.factory("GeolocationService", ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope',
    function($q, $window, $rootScope) {
        return function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!$window.navigator) {


                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
                });
            } else {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(position);
                    });
                }, function(error) {

                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
]);
```

When I use it. It's giving me an error

PositionError {message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 404.", code: 2, PERMISSION_DENIED: 1, POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 2, TIMEOUT: 3}

Can anyone please help how to resolve it ??

Comment: Are you running your app locally (via file://) or a webserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition always fail in chrome and firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731963/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-always-fail-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: no i hosted this on localserver using node.js server

Comment: please remove this duplicate tag.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have your wifi connexion enabled to use `navigator.geolocation` (Even if you are not using it !)

More explanations [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852029/993880).